# How to set the height of a div inside a modal in order to make it scroll?

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-modal

I have a modal structured as followed:

```
  <div class="modal fade" id="editSaga" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body row">
            <div class="col-7 firstchild">
                <div class="firstchild-header">
                </div>
                <div class="firstchild-body1">
                    // some content
                </div>
                <div class="firstchild-body2">
                    // some other content
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to make the `firstchild-body2` content scroll when its content goes beyond the content of the parent which is the `class col-7` with the following style:

```
.col-7 {
    max-height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

I tried to use jquery and get the its height this way:

```
$(".firstchild-body2").height(`$("#editSaga .modal-content").height()` - $(".firstchild- 
 header").outerHeight() - $(".firstchild-body1").outerHeight());
```

but I did not work because I always includes the height of the overflowing elements.
Then I changed the `$("#editSaga .modal-content").height()` to `$(".col-7").height()`. but this solution also is not working at all. Any help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a working code example for you here:
https://codepen.io/solutionsswift/pen/GRvxLOd

To apply the correct scroll inside the firstchild-body2, u need to set its height to auto. Also u need to set the maximum height for the col-7.

With JS u can set the max-height value on the firstchild-body2 element so that it can apply the scrollbar automatically.

Do not forget to set the overflow: auto on the body2!

```js
const header = document.querySelector('.firstchild-header');
const body1 = document.querySelector('.firstchild-body1');
const body2 = document.querySelector('.firstchild-body2');
const col7 = document.querySelector('.col-7');

// Set the max-height = total height of col-7 minus the height of header and 

body2.style.maxHeight = col7.offsetHeight - header.offsetHeight - body1.offsetHeight + 'px';
```

```css
.modal-body {
    height: 100%;
    max-height: 80px;
}

   
.col-7 {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: auto; 
  background-color: red;
}

.firstchild-body2 {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: auto;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="modal-dialog modal-lg modal-dialog-scrollable">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-body row">
            <div class="col-7 firstchild">
                <div class="firstchild-header">
                  header
                </div>
                <div class="firstchild-body1">
                    Body 1
                </div>
                <div class="firstchild-body2">
                    Body 2 sdfsdf sfsdf ssdf sf sd fsd fs fs fs fs 
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-5">
            </div>
        <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: U can remove the text 'header' and 'Body 1' to see it working. Scroll will dissappear if there is enough space for body2. Scroll will appear if it has not enough space.

Comment: You are setting the height of the col-7 to certain amount of pixels in my case its content is dynamic and the body one and header contents are always fixed only the content of body 2 can change depending on the received data. so I want to set its max-height to be equal to the modal content content height.

Comment: And also since the modal height might  differ depending on the viewport it needs to be get dynamically if I am not mistaking.

Comment: It will still work the same, the 80 pixels was just as an example. I don't have all your code, but i show the solutions for your scrolling issue :) U can ofcourse calculate the height of col-7 and replace the 80 with document.querySelector('.col-7').offsetHeight

Comment: I updated the codepen so that u can see it working with variable heights https://codepen.io/solutionsswift/pen/GRvxLOd 
I have set the modal-body for now on max-height 80px. U can set this to a percentage based on the viewport as well. :D

Comment: How can I set its height based on the height of the modal content? that's where I am failing.

Comment: I showed you how u can do that, u can do also height instead of maxHeight.
body2.style.height = col7.offsetHeight - header.offsetHeight - body1.offsetHeight + 'px'; If that is still not the answer on your qeustion, then u should explain better want you are trying to achieve. Also it feels incorrect tto set a height here, why do u want that?

Comment: If I do set its height like this document.querySelector(".modal-content").offset i will always give me more since I see all the modal scrolliing

Comment: It is working like a charm man thanks a lot.